# Creating Envelopes and Labels with Word using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a requirement to write data into ms-word in "Envelope Label" format.
I have used poi api XWPFDocument which is supporting table creation.
Can any one please suggest which library does supports the requirement and if possible please can you give me sample example.

Thank you,
Kavitha

Answer (score 0):

you may use a Word Template and replace the placeholder with real value.
Please refer to the sample in link: [link to replace text in MS Word using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615594/replacing-variables-in-a-word-document-template-with-java)